# Does jcrop work before uploading by sending the xy to php to crop?

Tags: php, jcrop

I've never messed with cropping images before upload until today. I have a basic understanding of resizing them with PHP but not before upload. My question is if how I get them to crop with jcrop is by sending the x and y coordinates to a php script and then crop the image based off that? Sorry if this is confusing, I can't find much information on the internet that helps with this. Any help would be great.

Comment: To crop the image the image has to be on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with another cropping program that worked better for my application.